# Using UIKit 3 Icons in React

Tags: reactjs, icons, getuikit

I'm trying to use UIKit icons in a React project. However, they don't show at all. I'm using npm and I'm running the following code:

```
import '../node_modules/uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css';
import '../node_modules/uikit/dist/js/uikit.min.js';
import '../node_modules/uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js';

<span data-uk-icon="social" className="uk-text-large"/>
```

Comment: open browser console, if the path is not correct, it will show 404 for missing files .. or use "react icon factory"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by deleting these:

```
import '../node_modules/uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css';
import '../node_modules/uikit/dist/js/uikit.min.js';
import '../node_modules/uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js';
```

And adding these into the  of the /public/index.html file:

```
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.42/css/uikit.min.css" />

<!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.42/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.42/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import UIkit from 'uikit';
import Icons from 'uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons';

// loads the Icon plugin
UIkit.use(Icons);
```

Source: https://github.com/uikit/uikit/issues/2229#issuecomment-398972606

Answer (score 2):

If using `yarn` or `npm` to install UIKit, in the root javascript file of react `src/index.js` you can add these

```
// UIKit import
import 'uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css'
import UIkit from 'uikit'
import Icons from 'uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons'

// loads the Icon plugin
UIkit.use(Icons)
```

Then won't need to put anything into `public/index.html`

Answer (score 1):

If you use SSR, wrap `UIkit.use(Icons)` in `useEffect`.

NextJS example:

```
// _app.jsx
import UIkit from 'uikit'
import Icons from 'uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    UIkit.use(Icons)
  })

  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```